# Excel Vlookup with wildcards & multiple lookup values or Join in Excel Data Model

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got the following two data tables;

Texts

| SearchA | SearchB | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Random | Text | Note A |
| Special | Characters | Note B |

Extended

| Text Locations | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Library | Random text can lead to more questions |
| Library | Sometimes random text can lead to answers |
| Internet | Special characters have meaning |
| Internet | Sometimes special characters can be a pain |

I'd like to do a vlookup with the extended table to bring across the Note field, I also have other  fields that I'd like to bring across and then I can create a pivot table to summarize some of the information, but I'm struggling to write a vlookup to do this or relate the two in PowerPivot.
I'm expecting to match `Random` & `Text` to the first two rows in the "Extended" table.

Are there any solutions that can do this?

| Text Locations | Text | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Library | Random text can lead to more questions | Note A |
| Library | Sometimes random text can lead to answers | Note A |
| Internet | Special characters have meaning | Note B |
| Internet | Sometimes special characters can be a pain | Note B |

@user11222393 has got the perfect solution for this.

Can anyone bring the first available value if one is applicable back from the Extended table into the Texts Table?

| SearchA | SearchB | Note | First Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Random | Text | Note A | Library |
| Special | Characters | Note B | Internet |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work in your data example:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($C$2:$C$3,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$3,B7))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$3,B7))),"Not found")
```

[image]

Wrap with `TOROW` if it is possible to get both *Note*:

```
=TOROW(IFERROR(FILTER($C$2:$C$3,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$3,P15))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$3,P15))),"Not found"))
```

[image]

Also:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($C$2:$C$3,BYROW($A$2:$B$3,LAMBDA(x,PRODUCT(BYCOL(x,LAMBDA(z,N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(z,B7))))))))),"Not found")
```

If you have *SearchA...SearchN*

Comment: Thanks that works great - Is there a way the search could also be applied in the reverse direction to bring over any of the Locations into the top table?

Comment: I don't follow you. Could you please update your post with data example and desired result?

Comment: Thanks - I've appended the extra question to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This formula returns the text locations from the extended table to the texts table.

Within the LET function the extended formula is user11222393's formula with spilled results. The extended formula is in cell I3 in the sheet and it spills down the results.

=LET(extended,BYROW(G3:G9,LAMBDA(r,TOROW(IFERROR(FILTER(C3:C4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3:A4,r))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B3:B4,r))),"Not found")))),BYROW(C3:C4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(FILTER(F3:F9,extended=x))))))

[image: Excel Vlookup with wildcards & multiple lookup values or Join in Excel Data Model]